# Angular 8 dot net core How to upload multiple files as part of complex object property

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, .net-core, webapi

I want to upload files from angular 8 and dot net core

```
public class democlass {


  public int TaskId {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public int FileTypeId {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string fileType {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public IFormFile file {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

[HttpPost("FileUpload")]
public async Task < IActionResult > Index(List of fileupload) {}
```

Frontend: Angular 8
BackEnd: dot net core

I want to upload files from frontend typescript and I also want to pass an extra parameter with each file upload so in that case file will be converted as a c# property so I want to pass multiple files with all its required information file wise

Comment: You do not need all those properties if all you need is the fileype, extension, name etc... all you need is a parameter of type List<IFormFile> also you will need to post it as FormData from javascript and the name of the field HAS TO MATCH the name of the parameter. For some reason it fails for me when it does not.

Comment: Also you might want to return something indicating if the upload was a success or not. I like returning json so when I make my post request from javascript I set the dataType to json.

Comment: I want pass custom properties with fileupload this is different for all files

Comment: That might be a tough one because my guess is you will have to construct a separate FormData object for each file..... Kind of like a separate form and then make a separate http request per file.  To upload a file you have to pass it as form data so it is kind of like a form.  A single input of type file can hold may files.  But FormData is not as flexible as constructing a json object for example.  You will also have to pass the anti forgery token in the header to not "confuse" the body of the request.

Comment: You would also try to construct a list of democlass and try to pass that.  You can get a file from a file input like this: fileInputElement.files[0]; that will get the first file in the collection.